# RxJava - Backpressuring keyboard inputs?

Tags: javafx, rx-java, kotlin, backpressure, rx-kotlin

Here's a fun RxJava problem.

I want to use RxJava backpressure operators to quickly lookup a typed input while each character is being typed, much like Google does on its search page. I went through the [Backpressure](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Backpressure) documentation and I came up with this (I am using RxJavaFX/RxKotlinFX to leverage JavaFX).

```
val myControl: Node = ...
val burstyMulticast = myControl.events(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED).publish().refCount()
val burstyDebounced = burstyMulticast.debounce(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
val burstyBuffered = burstyMulticast.buffer(burstyDebounced)

burstyBuffered
        .flatMap { it.toObservable().map { it.character }.reduce("") { x,y -> x + y } }
        .subscribe { println(it) }
```

This works great. If I type "Hello" against the control it will emit the `String` "Hello" after 200 ms of no typing. But if I want this to truly be more responsive, I should actually have some sort of rolling accumulation for each keystroke input.  Then my console output should really look like this:

```
H
He
Hel
Hell
Hello
```

Those should be all my emissions when I type the word "Hello", and the 200ms defines how much time should elapse before the accumulation resets. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! I figured out that I actually don't want `buffer()`, but rather a `switchMap()` and a `scan()` inside of it. I use a multicast to drive both the timer reset emission pushed into `switchMap()`, and the `scan()` which will infinitely concatenate typed characters until the `switchMap()` kills it for resetting.

```
val burstyMulticast = events(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED).publish().refCount().map { it.character }

burstyMulticast.throttleLast(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).startWith("")
        .switchMap {
            burstyMulticast.scan { x,y -> x + y }
        }.subscribe { println(it) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [throttleLast](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/sample.html) instead of denounce.

throttleLast will emit the most recent items emitted by an Observable within periodic time intervals

throttleLast o/p console

```
H
Hel
Hello
```

Comment: This feels closer to the solution, but still getting a delay before any emissions happen...

Comment: Nice :) now it seems you have found solution .!! As you have answered.

Comment: Thanks for your help though. It got me started, and I decided to tackle learning backpressure for the first time tonight.